# Magento 2.3.0 admin panel issue

Tags: admin, magento2.3.0

i am using `Godaddy share hosting` and `magento 2.3.0` and i install `magento 2.3.0` successfully but when i open my magento `admin panel` it show an error

> File not Found (404 error)

please give me solution.

[image]

Comment: you should be installing your Magento in a directory inside your web root directory not direct to the web root directory especially if it's a shared host then you can set from .htaccess to point your rewriteBase to that path

Comment: can you guid me step by step how can i done it? please

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution :

1) Enable Rewrite mode : `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

2) Configure apache :
For Ubuntu / Debian edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. To edit this file run command

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Modify from:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3) Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Reference : https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-404-page-not-found.html

Comment: I am using microsoft window not ubunto

Comment: so i can't understand how i solve this problem can you guid me properly